# huge bitarray/bit map declaration in C

Tags: c, bitmap

I am trying to write a bloom filter that stores say around 80,000 strings...Now i am guessing each string can be 2words length. To store 80,000 strings..i'll need 80,000*2 = 16kBytes?

If I have to store 16kB = 16*1000*8 = 128,000bits, I'll need a bitmap of 2^17=131,072 atleast. This is what I have right now

int main() {

```
char *str = "hello world";
int c = sizeof(unsigned char);
/*
 * declare the bit array
 */
unsigned char bit_arr[128000/c];
/*
 * couple of hash functions
 */   
unsigned int bkd = bkdrhash(str, strlen(str));
unsigned int rsh = rshash(str, strlen(str));
unsigned int jsh = jshash(str, strlen(str));

/* 
 * logic to set bit 
 * Access the bitmap arr element
 * And then set the required bits in that element
 */
bit_arr[bkd/c] & (1 << (bkd%c));
bit_arr[rsh/c] & (1 << (rsh%c));
bit_arr[jsh/c] & (1 << (jsh %c));
```

}

Is there a better/optimal way to do this?

thanks

Comment: Just saying you should probably say it is c for the language.

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned char) == 1` ALWAYS -- you might want `CHAR_BIT` from `<limits.h>` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your math is off. 80k * 2 = 160K.  Still as Chris Dodd said these are quite small on an average desktop machine or even a smart phone.  If your application is embedded or if you have other large allocations, then it may be a different story.  An iPhone has a 1 megabyte stack by default and 1/2 megabyte in secondary threads.

On a machine with busses N bits wide, there is probably a significant advantage to using integers N bits wide.  So abstract away from the word size:

```
#define WORD_BYTES 4
#define BYTE_BITS 8
#define WORD_BITS (BYTE_BITS * WORD_BYTES)
#define BITSET_BITS (1u << 17)
#define BITSET_WORDS (BITSET_BITS / WORD_BITS)
typedef unsigned int WORD;
typedef WORD BITSET[BITSET_WORDS];
typedef WORD *BITSET_REF;
#define bit(N) (1u << (N))

/*  Allocate a bitset on the heap and return a reference to it. */
BITSET_REF new_bitset(void)
{
  return safe_malloc(sizeof(BITSET));
}

/* Arrange for these functions to be inlined by the compiler rather 
   than using fancy macros or open coding.  It will be better in 
   the long run. */
int is_set(BITSET_REF bitset, int n)
{
  return (bitset[n / WORD_BITS] | bit(n % WORD_BITS)) != 0;
}

void set(BITSET_REF bitset, int n) 
{
  bitset[n / WORD_BITS] |= bit(n % WORD_BITS);
}

void clear(BITSET_REF bitset, int n) 
{
  bitset[n / WORD_BITS] &= ~bit(n % WORD_BITS);
}
```

Comment: Much better to use `#define WORD_BITS (sizeof(WORD) * CHAR_BIT)`

Comment: The sizeof has the advantage of saving a couple of characters of typing if you change the width of WORD. On the other hand you can't use sizeof in preprocessor directives with at least some compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the various apparent typos, allocating large arrays on the stack (as local variables) is generally a bad idea.  The stack defaults to not being huge (usually only about 8MB or so), and while you can reconfigure things to get a larger stack you're generally much better off allocating large objects on the heap or using static allocation.

That said, 128K is definitely not 'huge'.  By many measures its not even 'large'.  About the only thing you can say about it is that its not 'small'